# MongoDB Java -3.x , Specific Keys from Large dataset as per mongoshell pgmm

Tags: java, mongodb, nosql

Spec: mongo-java-driver-3.3.0.jar,jdk1.7,Mongodb 3.0.12

```
MongoShell : db.getCollection("Table-WEBSRVS-DTLS").find({"col1":"1000","col4":"EMEA"},{"col1":"1","col2":"1"})
```

Question : How to achieve this mongoshell command in Java for Mongo-java 3.x API ?

thx

Comment: Can you please provide a sample document for testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the equivalent Java code for the above query. You may need to change the database and collection names accordingly in the below code.

```
import org.bson.Document;

import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.FindIterable;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import com.mongodb.client.model.Filters;
import com.mongodb.client.model.Projections;

public class GetDataFromTableWebsrvsDtls {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MongoClient client = new MongoClient();

        MongoDatabase database = client.getDatabase("localhost");

        MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("TableWebsrvsDtls");

        FindIterable<Document> collectionData = collection
                .find(Filters.and(Filters.eq("col1", "1000"), Filters.eq("col4", "EMEA")))
                .projection(Projections.include("col1", "col2"));

        for (Document doc : collectionData) {
            System.out.println(doc.toJson());
        }

        client.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, thx for quick reply ,however with mongo-java-driver-3.4.0.jar  and Mongodb 3.0.12 ..The code did not yeald any results.

Any suggestions ??

Comment: Did you change the database name and collection name (should be Table-WEBSRVS-DTLS) as per your environment? Are you running the local MongoDB server? Is it like you are getting 0 documents or getting any error?

Comment: Oops , Sorry , I did get results,... small typos mistake, also can i use 
Projections.exclude to remove "_id" col ??


Thx for the help